# jquery ajax call response never returns

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working on app which is making ajax calls and I have come across some rather peculiar behaviour sometimes when an ajax call is fired it duplicates itself and the second one completes but I don't get the response back and original one keeps on loading forever this is fixed when an ajax call is fired again or when I hit refresh.

The problem is I cant reproduce this behaviour because it happens randomly. Most of the times when the tab is left open and I'm on a different tab or program.

The only thing I have noticed using firebug is that there seems to be something wrong with the response headers.

Compared to a successful call they are in a different order and some of the info is missing completely. The `Content-Type` has always more types than `text/html` which I’m defining in my `$.ajaxSetup`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType:'html',
  cache:false,
  type:'POST',
  timeout:15000,
  error:function() {
    alert('Action aborted please try again');
  },
  complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
    //console.log('XMLHttpRequest.readyState : '+XMLHttpRequest.readyState+'\nXMLHttpRequest.statusText : '+XMLHttpRequest.statusText+'\nXMLHttpRequest.status : '+XMLHttpRequest.status+'\ntextStatus : '+textStatus);
  }
 });
```

and an example of my ajax calls:

```
var dataString = 'value='+value+'&value1='+value1+'&value2='+value2;
   $.ajax({
    url:'file.php',
    data:dataString,
    success:function(resp){
      alert(resp);

    }
   })
```

this behaviour was happening a lot more often before I added a `dataType` and also it is happening more often when viewed locally on a winXP SP3 machine using xampp and I think both firefox and IE.

I have tested in a server running windows server 2008 and apache and php standalones not xampp that is and is happening even less.
Form my home pc it almost never happens the above testing was in my office pc.

has anyone came across similar type of behaviour or maybe is there a way to code my ajax calls differently.

I'd like to avoid using a plugin and long polling seems to fall a bit heavy on apache server.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the jquery ajax call is technically correct. One suggestions I would make is to not build the data string manually as you have. You can pass an object literal to the data parameter and let jquery do the string conversion for you. This has the added benefit of letting jquery perform proper escaping which can sometimes mess with an XMLHttpRequest
Other than that, I would recommend using firebug's console.trace() command to see if you are actually making two .ajax calls and why. There is a 'beforeSend' listener that you could set in your ajaxSetup - might be a good place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
var dataString= {
    value: value,  
    value1: value1
};
```

I’m almost definitely sure that only one call fires at a time but then if it takes too long it duplicates itself and continues loading forever.

I’m attaching a screenshot from firebug:

[image: Firebug]

Comment: it's like the original request never completes but instead im getting a response which was never actually requested